# Conditional compilation based on a compiler directive in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, delphi-2009, conditional-statements, directive

Is there a way in Delphi 2009 to have a section of code conditionally compiled based on a compiler directive. Specifically, I'd like to have code in place that is only included if the range-check compiler directive is turned on.

Something like this:

{$ifdef RANGECHECKINGISON}
[do range checking code here]
{$endif}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `{$ifopt}` instead of `{$ifdef}`:

```
{$ifopt R+} // if range checking is active
...
{$endif}
```

Comment: It's a pity you can't say "{$IFOPT RANGECHECKS ON}". :-/